# Do an Action after UIWebView Fully Loads

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, uiwebview

Is there any way for me to run some code when the WebView fully loads the page?
This is the code I'm using to open the web page in the view if this helps.

```
//Load URL Into WebView
NSString *urlAddress = @"http://example.com";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];
NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[[_listenupwebkit mainFrame] loadRequest:requestObj];
```

## My **.m** file

```
- (IBAction)SignInButton:(id)sender {
//Load URL Into WebView

NSString *urlAddress = @"http://www.pandora.com/account/sign-in";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];
NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[_listenupwebkit setFrameLoadDelegate:delegate];
[[_listenupwebkit mainFrame] loadRequest:requestObj];


loginbutton.hidden = YES;
webkithome.enabled = YES;



}
```

### **And**

```
- (void)webView:(WebView *)sender didFinishLoadForFrame:(WebFrame*)frame
{
    if(frame == [sender mainFrame]) {
        NSLog(@"viewDidLoad");
    }
}
```

## My **.h** file

```
- (void)webView:(WebView *)sender didFinishLoadForFrame:(WebFrame*)frame;
@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provide an implementation for

```
- (void)webView:(WebView *)sender didFinishLoadForFrame:(WebFrame*)frame
```

in your `frameLoadDelegate`.

```
[_listenupwebkit setFrameLoadDelegate:delegate];
[[_listenupwebkit mainFrame] loadRequest:requestObj];
```

In the method implementation, check to see if the finished frame is the main frame:

```
 - (void)webView:(WebView *)sender didFinishLoadForFrame:(WebFrame*)frame
 {
    if(frame == [sender mainFrame]) {
```

Comment: It gives me this error **Use of undeclared identifier 'delegate'.** I'm not 100% sure that I have the code in the right areas either.

Comment: @s0ulp1xel **common sense.** You need to substitute the actual names of the appropriate objects.

Comment: yeah, `delegate` represents the object that will act as a delegate, i.e., where you define the `didFinishLoadForFrame` method. It could be `self`, e.g., if the class that owns `_listenupwebkit` is where you put that method.

Comment: @sergio I just updated my original post with my updated code in the files that their in.

Comment: @sergio it works now but how can I have it only run the code for when it loads a specific URL?

Comment: You can check against `[[[WebFrame dataSource] request] URL]` or `[[[WebFrame dataSource] initialRequest] URL]`...